# Find the tables affected by user error & reverse the mistake

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm working on an Oracle database with an error made by a user. The issue is a number of person records were moved into a different "round". Each round has "episodes": Wrong "round" means all the episode processing has been affected (episodes skipped over). These users won't receive mails they were supposed to receive as a result of missed "episodes".

I have a query put together that identifies all the records that have been mistakenly updated. I need a way to modify the query to help find **all tables** that have been wrongly moved into "round 2".

(All the tables I need to identify are ones featuring the "round_no" value)

EDIT: There are over 70+ tables! With "ROUND_NO" COLUMN, I need to only identify the ones with these person records found in them.

**I also need to then take this data and return it back to round 1, from the incorrect round 2.**

Here is the query that identifies persons that have been "skipped" into round 2 in error:

```
SELECT p.person_id
,      p.name
,      ep2.open_date
,      ( SELECT pr1.open_date 
         FROM   Person_ep ep1 
         WHERE  ep1.person_id = ep2.person_id
         AND    er1.round_no  = 1 /* SOMETHING IS MISSING WHERE, WHERE IS er1 defined */
       ) 
       r1epiopen /* Round 1 episode open date */
FROM   person p
join   region r
on     r.region_code = p.region_code
and    r.location_id = 50
join   Person_ep er2
ON     er2.person_id = p.person_id
AND    er2.round_no  = 2
ORDER 
BY     p.person_id
```

Using SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 on an Oracle 11G RDBMS.

Comment: You want a list of tables with a `round_no` column; or you want to query all the tables in one go? You can't really do that without dynamic SQL, and if this is a one-off it's probably going to be easier to just copy/edit the code manually for each possible table name?

Comment: Hi, A list with round_no would be good. :) (That these specific persons exist in)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try to explain better.

Comment: A user incorrectly moved a bunch of users into episode 2 in error, I've identified the persons on the database that have been affected, now I want a way to undo the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to see this post that late... Hope it's not too late...

I suppose you are using Oracle 10+, and you know approximately the hour of the crime (!).

I see 2 possibilities:

1) Use the Log Miner to review the executed SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm

2) Use the flashback query to review data of a table in the past. But for this one you need to test in on every suspected table (70+) :( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01001

On the suspected table you could run this kind of SQL to see if update occurred in timeframe:
SELECT versions_startscn, versions_starttime, 
       versions_endscn, versions_endtime,
       versions_xid, versions_operation,
       description
FROM   my_table 
       VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-29 14:59:08', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-29 14:59:36', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE  id = 1;

I have no practical experience using log miner but I think it would be the best solution, especially if you have archive log activated :D

You can access the data values of affected table before the update (if you know the time of the update) using a query like this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-29 13:34:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Of course, data will be available only if still available (retention in undo tablepace).

You could then create a temp table with data before the update:

```
create table tempTableA as SELECT * FROM myTable AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-29 13:34:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Then update you table with values coming from tempTableA.

Comment: Finding the tables affected is the first step, actually rolling back the mistake is what I am in most need of.

Comment: Using flashback query you can access the record values before the update, save them in a temporary table, and so update you actual table with old values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all tables with column "round_no" you probably should use this query

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name='round_no'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get only the tables you can update

```
SELECT table_name 
   FROM user_tab_columns c, user_tables t
   WHERE c.column_name = 'ROUND_NO'
   AND t.table_name = c.table_name;
```

should work

or for the purists

```
SELECT table_name 
   FROM user_tab_columns c
   JOIN user_tables t ON t.table_name = c.table_name
   WHERE c.column_name = 'ROUND_NO';
```